# Using text from one field in a table as a link in another field

Tags: jquery, html

I would like some input on a problem I have.

I have a page with a dynamically generated table with five columns and a lot of rows. The first column fields contain a title, and the fifth column fields contain a url (some of them are empty though).

I would like to be able to with jquery:

in each row -- if the fifth column field contains a url --
wrap the title from the first column field with an anchor element and use the url from the fifth column field in the same row as the href.

Is this possible? Thank you very much in advance.

The rendered html is as follows:

```
<table class="acf-dynamic-table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Film Title</th>
            <th>Credits</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Link to imdb</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Credit 1</td>
            <td>Year 1</td>
            <td>Type 1</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx1/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>Credit 2</td>
            <td>Year 2</td>
            <td>Type 2</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx2/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td>Credit 3</td>
            <td>Year 3</td>
            <td>Type 3</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx3/</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the rendered html? That would make answering the question a snap.

Comment: @Ted I just added the html as you asked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
$('tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:first').wrapInner(($.trim($(this).find('td:last').text()).length > 0 )? '<a href="' +$(this).find("td:last").text()+'"/>':'')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="acf-dynamic-table ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Film Title</th>
            <th>Credits</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Link to imdb</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Credit 1</td>
            <td>Year 1</td>
            <td>Type 1</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx1/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>Credit 2</td>
            <td>Year 2</td>
            <td>Type 2</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx2/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td>Credit 3</td>
            <td>Year 3</td>
            <td>Type 3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td>Credit 3</td>
            <td>Year 3</td>
            <td>Type 3</td>
            <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx3/</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Beautiful, with 80 fewer characters I'm accepting your answer instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysx9bd23/

```
$('.acf-dynamic-table tr').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(5)').text();
    if(link){
        var title = $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text();
        $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').html('<a href="'+ link +'">'+ title +'</a>')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I chose this as the answer because it also reflected the fact that I only wanted the script run if the link field contained a link.

Comment: @alxvo, Thank you! I learned a long time ago to read all the OP's asks ;)  I'm glad I could help!

Comment: The only problem, like Ted's answer, is that it fails and creates a link if the last cell in a row contains a space since the cell's content isn't being trimmed.

Comment: lol oops! I added that into my answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Good point @j08691 The problem with your code is that it wraps the entire td with the anchor element, instead of just the text inside of it.

Comment: touché - just changed wrap() to wrapInner() to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The selection process can be made even better at first place.
Why go through each tr or td when you can hit to the point with awesome selections in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tbody>tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text()) {
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td").first().wrap("<a href=" + $(this).text() + "><a/>");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="acf-dynamic-table ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Film Title</th>
      <th>Credits</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Link to imdb</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 1</td>
      <td>Credit 1</td>
      <td>Year 1</td>
      <td>Type 1</td>
      <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx1/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 2</td>
      <td>Credit 2</td>
      <td>Year 2</td>
      <td>Type 2</td>
      <td>http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxx2/</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Title 3</td>
      <td>Credit 3</td>
      <td>Year 3</td>
      <td>Type 3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, using a script like this:

```
$('.acf-dynamic-table tbody tr').each(function(index, element){
   var $ele = $(element),
       $first = $ele.find('td:first-child'),
       link = $ele.find('td:last-child').text(),
       title = $first.text();
    if(link){
        $first.html('<a href="'+link+'">'+title+'</a>');
    }
});
```

See [this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ej9xhkLz/3/)

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Noted that I missed the 'if there is a link' bit, and added that in. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it (more verbose for new programmers)

```
        $(function(){
            /* for each row in the table (you may want to narrow it down
               further if you have multiple tables with the same class and 
               only want to apply this to a specific table
            */
            $(".acf-dynamic-table tbody tr").each(function( index, row ){
                var firstCol = $(row).find("td").first(); // first column
                var lastCol = $(row).find("td").last();   // last column
                var linkURL = lastCol.text(); 
                var linktitle = firstCol.text(); 

                // if the last column has text (URL) - create anchor tag
                if( linkURL && linkURL != '' ){
                    var anchor = $("<a>");
                    anchor.attr( "href", linkURL);
                    anchor.html( linktitle );
                    lastCol.html(anchor);
                }
            });
        });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q6ec3kLf/)**